# Can't update highcharts data on button - var visibility or events handle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm very new in JS and don't understand some questions.

I have in my page:

```
<script...>

$(function() {                                                                                                                               

  var charts_data = <%= @elms.get_charts_data %>;                                                                                           
  var elms_chart; 

  $(document).ready(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    function create_elev_dist_chart() {                                                                                                        
    elms_chart = $("#elms_chart").highcharts({  
    ...
    series: [{       
         name: "H",
         pointInterval: 10,
         data: (function () {
           var el_data = [];
           var t = 1;
           for (var index in charts_data) {
             console.log(charts_data[index].el);
             el_data.push([t, charts_data[index].el]);
             t += charts_data[index].t;
           };           
           return el_data;
           })()
         },

...
});
</script>
```

I also wrote very simple function to update data on chart:

```
function set_elms_chart_data() {
  elms_chart.series[0].setData([1, 1]);
};
```

add button and event handler:

```
$('#button').click(set_elms_chart_data());
```

But, I don't know where to put these, or where I make mistake.
If I put these inside

```
$(function() {
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'elms_chart.series')
```

if inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'elms_chart.series[0]')
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem.

- How can I access chart?
- Where should I put code for event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing set_elms_chart_data immediately with the following code:

```
$('#button').click(set_elms_chart_data());
```

What you want to do is to use set_elms_chart_data as the callback function:

```
$('#button').click(set_elms_chart_data);
```